# Why passing variables through url in php not working?

Tags: php, html, parse-platform

I am trying to pass some variables through url in php. Im using the following script

```
$query1 = new ParseQuery("Drivers");
                 $query1->includeKey("driverUserId");
                 $query1->descending("createdAt");
                 $results1 = $query1->find();


                    $object1 = $results1[$i];
                     $uname=$object1->get('driverUserId');
                     echo '<a href="fetch-data.php?data=driver&uid='.$uname.'">'.$uname->get('name').'</a>';
                        echo '<td>'.$uname->get('name').'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$uname->get('username').'</td>';
```

But when I execute the page, script stopped working in this line.

```
echo '<a href="fetch-data.php?data=driver&uid='.$uname.'">'.$uname->get('name').'</a>';
```

When I removed `'.$uname.'` it worked fine.

Comment: Well, `$uname` appears to be an object, as illustrated by your use of `$uname->get('name')`, so you'll find PHP will fizzle when you try to concatenate an object with a string. What exactly does `$uname` contain?

Answer (score 2):

Because if `$uname` has a `->get()` method, it's obviously a class or an object and you can't directly use it like a string (if it hasn't any tostring modifiers). Try to write it like this (just guessing):

```
echo '<a href="fetch-data.php?data=driver&uid='.$uname->get("id").'">'.$uname->get('name').'</a>';
```

Comment: I am using parse.com php sdk, and its related with relational query. `$uname=$object1->get('driverUserId');` .This is the code I used .

Comment: Can you post a more complete code? It's hard to guess it here.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: What's your uid key in your table? Switch "id" with that.

Comment: yes, I tried like this. ` $id=$uname->get('objectId');` then `echo '<a href="fetch-data.php?data=driver&uid='.$id.'">'.$uname->get('name').'</a>';` but no value for $id

Comment: What happened? is the `$id` variable filled? Did the error message change? look at the php error log for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
$id=$uname->get('id');
$name=$uname->get('name');
echo '<a href="fetch-data.php?data=driver&uid='.$id.'">'.$name.'</a>';
```